# There is a table with a pcode with many dates in different rows. How can I select only the latest date for a pcode

Tags: sql, postgresql

image of the table is in the following link.

[image]

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: What is your attempt

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select max(prodate) from mytable
group by pcode
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the `rank` window function:

```
SELECT pcode, 
       prodate
FROM   (SELECT pcode, 
               prodate, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY pcode ORDER BY prodate DESC) rk
        FROM   mytable)
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.pcode, t2.max_date
from table1 t1
inner join
(
  select max(prodate) max_date, pcode
  from table1
  group by pcode
) t2
  on t1.pcode= t2.pcode
  and t1.prodate = t2.max_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Row_Number()** and **Partition By**:

```
SELECT X.pcode, 
       X.prodate
FROM   (SELECT pcode, 
               prodate, 
               Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY pcode ORDER BY prodate DESC) PartNo
        FROM  table) X
WHERE  X.PartNo = 1
```